# WCF Service crash localhost behavior

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service with NetTcpBinding and DuplexChannel self hosted in the console app. Clients 'subscribe' to the WCF service and i gather callbacks to the list. On client side I have attached handlers to the Faulted and Closed events and when I receive them I just reconnect the client again.

I have a strange behavior (as for me) when testing the crash of service:
When both client and service are tested on localhost I just kill the WCF Service process and clients receive the Faulted event and then try to reconnect all the time until the service is alive again.

When I deploy service on the production server and client is on another comp (over the internet, not in the same domain) when I kill the hosting process - clients don't receive any notification about the fault, although I have proper way to close the app when the Abort is sent to all of the callbacks in the list, when i close it in proper way - clients get the fault event and properly try to resubscribe.

So the question is, why this is happening? The question is not HOW to maintain the alive connection, i think i found how to do that in another way (reliable session or pinging the service)

I just want to know WHY the behavior of the event is different when deployed? The configuration is the same - i didn't change anything.

Comment: Did you check relation of the described behavior to network connection and windows security policies?

Comment: No I haven't, i even don't know where to look, that's why I asked the question here.